# Which protocol is used, OAuth2 or OpenId when NodeJs clients log in to Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I'm researching how NodeJs clients log in to Hyperledger Fabric. As explained  on page:
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/tree/master/examples/balance-transfer#running-the-sample-program

"The response (for a successful client login request) contains the success/failure status, an enrollment Secret and a JSON Web Token (JWT) that is a required string in the Request Headers for subsequent requests."

JWT defines a token format, and examples of protocols that use this format are OAuth/OAuth2, and OpenID Connect which is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth2 protocol.

Which of these protocols is used exactly by Hyperledger Fabric? The answer is not obvious. Googling :
+"hyperledger fabric" +openid
Or 
+"hyperledger fabric" +OAuth

returns no valid results.

OAuth2 is mentioned in a comment in code : https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/credentials.go

And OpenId is used in a method name in code :
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/core/ledger/kvledger/kv_ledger_provider.go

Any insight greatly appreciated.

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Fabric uses PKI to verify allowable messages (signature verification). It doesn't use the traditional OAuth.

Fabric-CA (Certificate Authority) is a separate component that issues certificates. You have an option to use Fabric-CA or other CA providers. The Node.js example you mentioned uses Fabric-CA, which allows one (a registrar) to register and enroll a user. See the document here http://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#overview

Once a user has a certificate issued by an authorized organization on the Fabric blockchain network, the user may send messages (eg transactions) to the network entities (peers and orderers). The Fabric peers and orderers verify each message signature to be valid and authorized in order to process the message. See this document for more detail http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html